# jQuery disable clicks temporarily

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website has lots of elements which trigger ajax data retrieval on click, and some drag&drop elements handled by jquery ui. Many elements use their own click events, attached directly to them. I need some functionality which will ignore all mouse clicks/mouseup/mousedown events temporarily under some predefined circumstances. For example, I want to disable drag & drop entirely until some ajax request is in progress, etc. I thought I would bind on click and preventDefault(), I tried to bind on document, like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "*", null, function(ev){ev.preventDefault();});
```

I think it's because when the event reaches $(document), it was already triggered on all childs, so it's too late to preventDefault().

One solution I could imagine is to set some global variable, like ignore_clicks=true; and then add to every function which handles mouse click a check if this variable is true or not. This seems very difficult and I'm afraid even impossible due to external click handlers like in jquery-ui code.

Another solution I imagine is to temporarily put some fixed style element, 100% width and 100% height, zero opacity, over the current page, but this doesn't seem like an ideal solution, feels more like a hack. Furthermore if there is any ongoing animation on the webpage while it is covered by transparent element, the performance of the animation is degraded.

Is there any simple and elegant solution which would allow me to temporarily block all mouse clicks on the given page? (mouseup & mousedown too).

Comment: Use .off() and then .on() again.

Comment: Have you checked the [eventPause](https://github.com/s-yadav/eventPause.js) library?

Comment: Since you're seeking to prevent nearly all interaction with the page while these AJAX events are processing, you may want to place a full screen modal over the page which displays a loading spinner.

However, I'd generally caution against such a modal or what you're doing in general.  It's bad user experience to have the whole page become unresponsive while a request completes.

Comment: Answers are bad, right way to do it would be to use `pointer-events` CSS property which would actually ignore clicks (not removing handlers that `prevaultDefault`ed before and cause form submits). Setting pointer-events would elegantly solve the issue.

Comment: Browser support for `pointer-events` seems to be worse than for capturing listeners, so I'll keep that answer selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to stop the event in the capturing phase by using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}, true /* true == capturing phase */);
```

Do note that this won't work in IE8.

Comment: This perfectly works as expected, since it captures the click before it reaches the elements. For my purpose I need to add listener separately on all three (click, mousedown, mouseup), and then it works.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent *all* mouse-based interactions, you could place an invisible overlay in front of the dom, e.g.

**HTML**

```
<div id="click-blocker" style="display: none;"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#click-blocker {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
// to disable clicks:
$('#click-blocker').show()

// to enable clicks again
$('#click-blocker').hide()
```

By `show`ing the `click-blocker`, all clicks will happen to the blocker, since it's in front of everything, but since it has no content or background, the user will perceive it as their clicks are just not doing anything.

This won't work if you only want to disable a specific type of interaction, e.g. drag+drop as you mentioned.

Comment: This degrades performance if there any any ongoing animations on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can toggle on/off event handlers:

```
function doClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default event.
    //do some fancy ajax stuf...
};

//Toggle on:
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', doClick);

//Toggle off:
$(document).off('click', '.clickable', doClick);
```

This will work with any event such as click/mousedown/mouseup etc.

If you want to prevent all other events from being fired, you could try as follows:

```
function preventPropagation(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
};

//Toggle on when ajax:
$(document).on('click mousedown mouseup', '*', preventPropagation);

//Toggle off when ajax finishes:
$(document).off('click mousedown mouseup', '*', preventPropagation);
```

Comment: So you suggest me to .off all click events on all elements on the page temporarily and then re-attach them with .on after the ajax completes? This is impossible to do, many of the elements have their own onclick handlers which were set by jquery ui for example, and I have no control over that.

Comment: You are right. Check my edit. I think i've missread your question the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think having a "processing" animation overlay is a hack and it seems pretty elegant to me. Plenty of applications use this because it gives users feedback. They know that the application is working and they'll have to wait.